# Convert dates in String data type with different formats column to Date data type in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I have a database table of String ( varchar ) type having dates. These dates are of the following formats (examples):

```
15-06-2018
15/06/2018
15-Jun-2018
15 June 2018
June 15, 2018
June, 15, 2018
```

Is there any query that can be used to obtain Date data type values from this using a PostgreSQL query?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a giant case expression:

```
(case when col ~ '^[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}$' then to_date(col, 'DD-MM-YYYY')
      when col ~ '^[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}$' then to_date(col, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
      when col ~ '^[0-9]{2}-[A-Za-z]{3}-[0-9]{4}$' then to_date(col, 'DD Mon YYYY')
      . . .
 end) as the_date
```